# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'select_s'

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Just calling this directly from the editor (Toad). No idea why getting the above error having checked the function definition and variable types repeatedly. All of the information available online seems to be for stored procedures - which I don't believe are used here

```
DECLARE
TYPE attrs_type is VARRAY(10) of STRING(10);
l_ldap_host VARCHAR(255) := 'SERVERNAME';
l_ldap_port INT := 389;
l_ldap_user VARCHAR(255) := 'USERNAME';
l_ldap_passwd VARCHAR(255) := 'PASSWORD';
l_ldap_base VARCHAR(255) := 'l=something,dc=something';
l_session DBMS_LDAP.session;
l_retval NUMBER;
l_entry VARCHAR(255);
l_attrs attrs_type;
l_message VARCHAR(255) := null;
l_filter VARCHAR(255) := 'objectclass=*';

BEGIN
l_session := DBMS_LDAP.init(hostname => l_ldap_host,
                             portnum => l_ldap_port);
l_retval := DBMS_LDAP.simple_bind_s(ld => l_session,
                                    dn => l_ldap_user,
                                passwd => l_ldap_passwd);
l_attrs(1) := '*'; -- retrieve all attributes                      
l_retval := DBMS_LDAP.search_s(
                             ld => l_session,
                             base => l_ldap_base,
                             scope => DBMS_LDAP.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                             filter => l_filter,
                             attrs => l_attrs,
                             attronly => 0,
                             res => l_message);  
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_message);
-- code to do stuff                   
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `l_attrs` as `dbms_ldap.string_collection`, not your own type. Even if your type is defined in the same way, it will not be interchangeable with another apparently-similar type. To Oracle, your `attrs_type` is *not* the same as `string_collection`. Hence the error you're getting - you are indeed using the wrong type for that argument.

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS00511):

> A collection type defined in a package specification is incompatible with an identically defined local or standalone collection type.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. For some reason documentation alluding to the existence of this unique datatype is rather sparse, but I was able to track some down now that I know what I'm looking for.